# Black magic of pointers

Tags: c#, c

I have a `uint8_t state [16][8]` with such values:

```
86 a9 d2 4e 23 f4 b1 3
b7 2b 8c 69 d1 f1 bb b5
11 7e c3 1 76 4 dc df
6b f0 4f 3d a9 5c 2 68
8 f4 ee 6f 1b e6 90 3b
32 4c 4e 27 99 c b2 4e
f6 9d d5 8d be 84 81 3e
e0 a5 2f 66 31 23 98 75
e4 52 cf 77 42 ad 3 61
40 6b 32 61 2 0 1 0
0 0 fd 60 56 1d c 61
4f cb 22 0 ff ff ff ff
2 0 1 0 e8 98 8 61
fd 6e 22 61 94 60 cf 77
ac a2 d0 77 20 64 2e 61
0 0 0 0 10 cc 22 0
```

When I do

```
uint64_t* s = (uint64_t*)state;
```

and then print `uint64t* s`, I get such `uint64_t` values:

```
4ed2a986
698c2bb7
1c37e11
3d4ff06b
6feef408
274e4c32
8dd59df6
662fa5e0
```

Can somebody explain me the "black magic" of the conversion?

More specific, I need to port this convertion from C function to C# method.

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You are right

Comment: Should probably be mentioned, those aren't `uint64_t`s.

Comment: BTW, you probably broke strict aliasing rule and so have UB.

Comment: @Jarod42, I think the OP didn't write the C code, and I think they didn't understand what you were trying to communicate to them. I didn't mention the possible boundary issues in my answer since the OP is trying to write matching C# code, not fix someone else's C code (that works even if it's not portable).

Answer (score 2):

On [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) machines (such as x86 and x64 machines), the bytes of integers are ordered from least-significant to most-significant. For example, the 64-bit integer

```
0x1234567890ABCDEF0
```

is stored as follows in memory:

```
F0 DE BC 9A 78 56 34 12
```

So, on a little-endian machine, the C code you provided actually produces the following numbers:

```
86 a9 d2 4e 23 f4 b1 03 = 0x03b1f4234ed2a986 =   266262285475031430
b7 2b 8c 69 d1 f1 bb b5 = 0xb5bbf1d1698c2bb7 = 13095326223231101879
11 7e c3 01 76 04 dc df = 0xdfdc047601c37e11 = 16130772870216515089
6b f0 4f 3d a9 5c 02 68 = 0x68025ca93d4ff06b =  7494654611845804139
08 f4 ee 6f 1b e6 90 3b = 0x3b90e61b6feef408 =  4292183450400519176
32 4c 4e 27 99 0c b2 4e = 0x4eb20c99274e4c32 =  5670608732741848114
f6 9d d5 8d be 84 81 3e = 0x3e8184be8dd59df6 =  4504027056305446390
e0 a5 2f 66 31 23 98 75 = 0x75982331662fa5e0 =  8473561393972356576
e4 52 cf 77 42 ad 03 61 = 0x6103ad4277cf52e4 =  6990621547598664420
40 6b 32 61 02 00 01 00 = 0x0001000261326b40 =      281485197339456
00 00 fd 60 56 1d 0c 61 = 0x610c1d5660fd0000 =  6992996578231123968
4f cb 22 00 ff ff ff ff = 0xffffffff0022cb4f = 18446744069416864591
02 00 01 00 e8 98 08 61 = 0x610898e800010002 =  6992006543692595202
fd 6e 22 61 94 60 cf 77 = 0x77cf609461226efd =  8633225201093603069
ac a2 d0 77 20 64 2e 61 = 0x612e642077d0a2ac =  7002644561219592876
00 00 00 00 10 cc 22 00 = 0x0022cc1000000000 =     9794518299705344
```

(You obtained different values because there was a bug in your print statement.)

On the same machine, the following code produces the same number:

```
ulong value = BitConverter.ToUInt64(data, 0);
```

Neither the provided C code nor this equivalent C# code should be used for data that's sent from one machine to another.

Answer (score 0):

When analyzing situations such as this, it's helpful to buffer your numbers with zero, so your `state` block actually becomes

```
86 a9 d2 4e 23 f4 b1 03
b7 2b 8c 69 d1 f1 bb b5
11 7e c3 01 76 04 dc df
6b f0 4f 3d a9 5c 02 68
08 f4 ee 6f 1b e6 90 3b
32 4c 4e 27 99 0c b2 4e
f6 9d d5 8d be 84 81 3e
e0 a5 2f 66 31 23 98 75
e4 52 cf 77 42 ad 03 61
40 6b 32 61 02 00 01 00
00 00 fd 60 56 1d 0c 61
4f cb 22 00 ff ff ff ff
02 00 01 00 e8 98 08 61
fd 6e 22 61 94 60 cf 77
ac a2 d0 77 20 64 2e 61
00 00 00 00 10 cc 22 00
```

From there, each of your results in `s` is clearly the first half of each line, with (as mentioned by chris in comments) reversed [Endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Per cHao's comment, the results do not appear to be 64 bits long, resulting in this "first half" problem; these results seem to be the result of converting to a `uint32_t` rather than 64, as they're only 32 bits each.

Comment: Re "*From there, each of your results in s is clearly the first half of each line, with (as mentioned by chris in comments) reversed Endianess.*", No, `s` contains `0x03b1f4234ed2a986`, which is formed from the **entire** line.

Comment: @ikegami , I'm only seeing `4ed2a986` as the first line in the question, which is where I'm getting my data. I didn't run the code since that part of the discussion has reached a "bad question data" state

Comment: The first line is `86 a9 d2 4e 23 f4 b1 3`, and `*s` contains `0x03b1f4234ed2a986` (not `0x4ed2a986`).

Comment: Probably you need to use %llx in your print statement.